# SVG circle not working in Chrome

Tags: css, google-chrome, svg

I’ve this svg code. It works fine in Firefox and Safari. But for some reason it doesn’t show up in Chrome. And I cant figure out why...

```
<svg version="1.1" id="red_rgb" viewBox="0 0 100 56" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg">
    <circle class="red" cx="50" cy="18" r="18"/>
    <circle class="green" cx="39" cy="37" r="18"/>
    <circle class="blue" cx="61" cy="37" r="18"/>
</svg>
```

and this CSS

```
.rgb_content    {
    width: 100%;
    height: 230%;
    position: absolute;
    left:0;
    top:12.5%; 
    z-index: 2;
    }       

.rgb_svg {
    position: absolute;
    z-index: 10;
}

circle.red {
    fill: red;
}

circle.green {
    fill: green;
}

circle.blue {
    fill: blue;
}   

circle.red, circle.green, circle.blue {
    mix-blend-mode: lighten;
}

.rgb_text {
    position: absolute;
    mix-blend-mode: hue;                
    z-index: 20;                
}
```

As said: It works fine in FireFox and Safari, but not in Chrome.
What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 3):

It's because "mix-blend-mode" [not fully supported in Chrome for SVG](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/mix-blend-mode)

But you can add "isolate" on a parent to circle container (like in MDN example):

> /* without isolation, the background color will be taken into account */

```
svg {isolation: isolate;}
circle.red, circle.green, circle.blue {
    mix-blend-mode: lighten;
}
```

That actually worked for me [(here is fiddle)](https://jsfiddle.net/oppin/cndq4cvr/1/)

Comment: @TemaniAfif, personally I find fiddles more comfortable, mater of taste, besides it's linked to acc, so should remain till that chrome behavior changed, also all essential code (1 line) I've added to answer )

Comment: ,.. ))) same goes about closing SO acc), and you can't play with SO code snippet, and it's editor is much-much less comfortable (IMHO ofcourse), so let's close this debate unless it's touched to the solution itself, k? it's definitely not SO-way